# Custom labels using ade4 and factoextra packages

Tags: r, pca, factoextra

I want to make and plot PCA with `ade4` package and then customize with `factoextra`. It works very well with both packages until I realize my biplot with `factoextra`, I don't know how to customize labels.

I would only know if somebody can help me with the following code I wrote:

```
fviz_pca_biplot(acp,geom=c("point","arrow"),label="var",col.circle="grey70",labelsize=4,alpha.var ="cos2",col.var="red",habillage = Biot,addEllipses =TRUE, ellipse.level = 0.95) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=seq(0,15))+
  scale_color_brewer(palette="Spectral")+
  theme_minimal()
```

That gave me this biplot:

[image]

I would have variable's name as "Cocco", "Crypto", "Diato" instead of "biot.Conc_cocco", "biot.conc_Crypto"

Thanks for your answers and advices

Comment: Just had the same problem, however I am using `prcomp` to generate the PCA. `factoextra` uses the variable names in your PCA's loadings/rotation. So in your case, find the names of `acp` (possibly using `acp$rotation` although I am not familiar with the package) and change the names. In my case I could use `PCA<-prcomp(data)`  `rownames(PCA$rotation)<-colnames(wherever you have stored the labels you want)`, then plot. Hope this helps.